# Error in connecting to Database in DB2 using python

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

When I tried to connect the DB2 database through the following python code
python version : 3.6
ibm_db version : ibm_db-2.0.9
DB2_version : 11.5

```
import configparser
import ibm_db_dbi       
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('File location')
server_name = config.get(conn_type, 'server_name')
database = config.get(conn_type, 'database')
username = config.get(conn_type, 'user')
password = config.get(conn_type, 'password')
conn = ibm_db_dbi.connect('Server='+server_name+';''Database='+database+';''UID=' + username + ';''PWD=' + password + ';')
print("Connection to Source established.")
```

I am getting the below error

```
unhashable type: 'list'
ERROR:root:<p>Error: unhashable type: 'list'</p>
```

Can someone please help me to solve this error

Comment: please edit your question to add missing information. your version of python, version of ibm_db,  version of the ibm_db module,, and change your code to print out (for debugging only) the full connection string before calling the connect() method, and which operating system runs python. Looks like you are missing required parts of the connection string (hostname, port, dbname etc)

Comment: and is your line to log the exception working...?

Comment: Missing `hostname=...;port=...;protocol=tcpip;` from connection string

Comment: Even though I add all these parameters, am still getting the same error

Comment: Please uninstall ibm_db v2.0.9  and install the current version 3.0.4 of ibm_db module.  Please edit your question to give missing detail of operating-system (version, distro etc),  and add a debug statement to show the full connection string. Some versions also need `DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBV DRIVER};` in the connection string but this varies with exactly which Db2-driver you are using (and your question gives no information about that).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't try your code but following is alternative for your code

```
In [1]: import ibm_db

In [2]: conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=SAMPLE;HOSTNAME=<hostname>;PORT=<port>;UID=db2inst1;PWD=password;","","")

In [3]:
```